# SQL Query to Display Values in Table for Logged In User

Tags: php, sql

I am just starting out, very much a rookie and any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have a list of URLs in a table called "url".  I have another table called "users" and in that table a column named "username" which list the users of the site. I am looking to display urls for the logged in user via a session value of $session->username but have not yet figured out how to only render URLS for the logged in user.

I apologise in advance, I may have the wrong idea but wanted to show you what I was attempting to do but am not able to get to work properly without SQL syntax errors.

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * from urls, users INNER JOIN username ON  
$session->username');
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Please show us the structure of the tables `urls` and `users`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a column named `user_id` which is making a relation b/w `users` and `urls` table. if that column name is named anything else replace the `user_id` with that column name

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * from users u JOIN urls ur 
                      ON  u.username = ur.username 
                      WHERE u.username="'.$session->username.'"');
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Shakti, your page rendered without error.  The page is rendering the table but isn't returning any URLs even when I log in as a user with entries.  The url table has a "user" column, can you relate that field to the users table for me?  Do you think that might be the issue?  Thanks!

Comment: @jeremy: What the `user` column contains? Is it supposed to hold `user_id` from `users` table?

Comment: The urls table contains a column named username which stores the person who submitted the URL.  For instance values in the column could be Bob, Ted, Betty.  There is also a username column in the users table with the same names.

Comment: Thanks.  If I do a print_r($_SESSION); on the page I get the following...Array ( [username] => jeremy [likeVoted1] => 1 [id] => 7 [cookie_id] => 9e5f06a9e8182b374dbcc2c949038b30 ) 

I don't get any URL values returned but I have hundreds of values in the database for that user.  

Table urls has column "user" and table users has column "username".

Thank you again!

Comment: @Jeremy: I think you are completely lost. Why you are checking the session value? print out the result of query we are running to get urls.

Comment: The query you are running doesn't produce any results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the index connection your urls to your user. An user_id for example. This would give you an query like:

```
$sQuery = "SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN urls ON urls.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.username = '".$oSession->username."'";
```

Comment: Thanks, forgive me if I made a mistake on my side.  The page is throwing less errors than Shakti's answer.  It is reporting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' (on the last line).  I think you're really close...thx!

Comment: Thank you very much, you are correct, I needed to tweak it slightly.  Below is what I have:

$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN urls ON urls.user= users.username
WHERE users.username = '".$oSession->username."'";

I am receiving the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'